# coverage on virtualenv includes tests of python standard libraries

Tags: python, code-coverage, python-unittest

I am trying to run test coverage of my code. Tests are located inside `tests` folder of my project. Without coverage I ran:

```
python -m unittest discover tests -vb
```

and ran all tests inside test directory. I tried using coverage report running

```
coverage run -m unittest discover test -vb
```

and then

```
coverage html
```

but the html report contains modules that are from the standard library or third party libraries that are included inside `site-packages` directory of my virtualenv. I thought coverage excluded this by default. How can I run coverage correctly to exclude everything outside my code? Shoulde I use the `--source` flag and set it to the root of my project e.g

```
 coverage run --source=<project_root> -m unittest discover test -vb
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectation is correct: by default you should not get stats for the python installed library. I'm running your command on a test of mine and only get coverage for my modules. With flag -L I get coverage for python installed modules. Is it possible you have a custom installation of coverage? Or the flag is somehow set in your configuration? What version of coverage do you use? From the history of versions, it seems the default for this option may be true for versions older than v3.0b.
If you run without -m unittest discover (simply execute one of the tests), do you still get the same?
You could try --debug=sys in case it produces useful info.

Comment: Using Coverage.py, version 4.2 with C extension
Setting the source to project root wokred. But after coverage is done executing I don't get results of the total coverage at once. I need to run report. Can it be done on the same step? I need to put it in my gitlab ci pipeline

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to run and report in the same command. Your use case does not let you execute one after the other? e.g.:
coverage run --source=<project_root> -m unittest discover test -vb || coverage report